# Why does this tabulate code make the right-aligned column text go too far to the right?

Tags: align, context

Here is my code, which makes some text left-aligned and others right-aligned, to the right of the left-aligned text:

```
    \starttabulate[|lw(.5\textwidth)|rw(.5\textwidth)|]
        \NR
        \NC Here is left-aligned text \NC Here is right-aligned text \NC\NR
        \NR
    \stoptabulate
```

When compiled, the right-aligned text is a cm or so too far to the right. I'm assuming that somehow the middle column has some extra space there, so that is why the text is too far.

How can I fix this so the right aligned text is right along the line of the edge of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it really helps reading the Wiki.

> [image]

To remove the column spacing around cells, you can use the `k` operator.  This is only documented in the [ConTeXt Reference Manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) as far as I can tell.

```
\showframe
\starttext

\starttabulate[|k0lw(.5\textwidth)|k0rw(.5\textwidth)|]
    \NC Here is left-aligned text \NC Here is right-aligned text \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can just subtract the column spacing from the width, although that becomes a bit unwieldy.

```
\showframe
\starttext

\starttabulate[%
    |%
    lw(\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\dimexpr\tabulationparameter{unit}\relax\relax)%
    |%
    rw(\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\dimexpr\tabulationparameter{unit}\relax\relax)%
    |%
]
    \NC Here is left-aligned text \NC Here is right-aligned text \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

[image]